# Twilio Flex stream audio over websocket

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex

I am trying to stream audio when an agent picks up call on a flex dashboard. Although one can start streaming when working with twilio APIs. But I didn't find any docs related to this usecase.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can insert the [fork stream widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/fork-stream) into the Studio flow that leads to a Flex agent?

**[edit]**

As requested, the media stream should join when the call is accepted by an agent. I don't think you can do this in Studio, so you would have to implement this as a [Flex plugin](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/plugins). When the plugin detects that a call has been accepted by an agent it could make a request using the call SID to modify the call and inject [the `<Start><Stream>` TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/stream).

I don't have more detail on that right now, as I've not built that sort of thing myself. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I only want to fork the stream, when the agent assignment has been done. I couldn't figure out the way to do this on twilio studio. It would be helpful if you can explain on twilio studio.

Comment: OK, updated with an idea about building a flex plugin that could do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Philnash, I will try and let you know. Currently I have added a callback to the task assignment in task router. After that I bridge the incoming call to the selected agent  and start stream using twiml. But this causes the call to be automatically picked up at the flex dashboard.