# Twilio Flex. Start a stream once an agent has accepted a task

Tags: stream, twilio, twilio-flex

so, the flow is, I call `enqueue` Twiml verb. It creates a task and assigning to a specific agent. I have a task router callback on `reservation.accepted` event. I got it, but once I update a customer call with `Stream` Twiml - it's removing a customer from the conference which Flex creates. I'd like to avoid it somehow. To avoid that I update a `customer` participant with `end_conference_on_exit: false` attribute. Then I update a customer call with `Stream` and `Dial.conference` to get a customer back to a conference which I do not like. Is there any easier way to implement it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Updating a call like that will always take it out of it's current TwiML flow and you would have to redirect back to where it was, like you have already implemented.

I know this is not starting the stream after the task is accepted, but I think the best way to implement this right now is to use the [fork stream Studio widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/fork-stream) directly before the send to Flex widget in the Studio Voice IVR flow.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I appreciate that, but I do not use Studio, so it does not work for me. Actually, it's not what I want to achieve. I'd like to start a stream not when a task is created but when was accepted, that's very important. A task could be in waiting queue for a long time. I don't want a stream to be running at that time

Comment: If you’re using Flex then you are using Studio and you have a Studio flow for both incoming calls and messages. You’re not the first to ask this, as it happens. I had some [other, less concrete, suggestions here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61222680/28376). Maybe that helps?

Comment: We manage a request via Webhook URL, not via Studio. We set on Flex Flow in Flex/Messaging page

Comment: Not sure what you mean there. Can you share a screen shot of your settings for this?

Comment: Sorry, I was confused you. We use a TwiML with URL to our Backend API

Comment: Ah, I only recently learned about how to set the Flex Flow, I apologise. I think what you are doing may be the best way to handle this. There were similar suggestions in [this question too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61211677/twilio-flex-stream-audio-over-websocket/61222680?noredirect=1#comment108307095_61222680).